# Updating a log file using s3fs

Tags: python, logging, amazon-s3, s3fs

If I use s3fs to mount a "folder", I can access to my log file.

Will the whole file be uploaded each time I add a new line through a Python script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the official git repo of s3fs located [here](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse)!

When you are using s3fs to mount a "folder", 
random writes or appends to files require rewriting the entire file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Note that this is optimized with server-side copy so that the client doesn't need to upload all the bytes again -- just the 5 MB regions that have changed.